# Typeahead in bootstrap 2.3

Tags: mysql, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, typeahead

I am beginner in CI. I try to make typeahead with Bootstrap and MySql, but always fail.
Is it possible to make typeahead in bootstrap 2.3 with combining MySql and Codeigniter?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
$result= $this->db->select('field')->get('table')->result();
foreach($result as $row){
$options[] = $row->field;
}   
//set $options in view
```

View:

`<input type="text" name="options"  class="typeahead" autocomplete="off"  value="" />`

Javascript:

```
$(function(){

    var options= <?=json_encode($options)?>;
    $('.typeahead').typeahead({source: options});
});
```

That's all

Comment: still not working. is it correct when i type this in javascript? <script type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function() {

    var search= <?=json_encode($search)?>;
    $('.typeahead').typeahead({source: search});
});
</script>

Comment: Sorry I forgot one thing, you have to create a simple array of options, I updated the controller